# searching in google from differents PC return different results

Tags: google-chrome, seo, keyword-search

I am searching for a specific keyword in google and from different computers I am getting different results. On one computer, the website I was expecting for is the 3rd on the first page and on other computer, the website is not listed at all in the first page.
Is there some cache that I need to clear in order to have the search returning unique results on all computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [Personalized Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Personalized_Search) feature uses search history to personalize your search results. Since all searches on Google Search are associated with a browser cookie record, previous search results and visited websites can be used to provide more relevant results.

See "Step 3" of Google's [Search and Browse Privately](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4540094?rd=1) support page to turn off result customization.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, your problem could be in the URL itself. This totally depends on the OS. (this is assuming you search is "keywords" and your OS is Ubuntu -->)If the OS'es are different, then it should be the client part in "https://www.google.com/search?q=keywords&client=ubuntu" (there are more parts to the url, but that's all i need to explain it. Just try taking out the client part from the URL.